# How to convert stream code to observable(reactive) in c#?

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, grpc

I have this code and it worked. How can I convert this code to `reactive programming` code? This code worked with `grpc server` send stream file to `grpc server` and get result of operation in message

```cs
foreach (var item in uploadedFiles)
{
    using (var call = client.TransferFiles(item))
    {
        while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
        {
            var currentFile = call.ResponseStream.Current;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(currentFile .Message);
        }
    }
}
```

`client.TransferFiles(item)` implement in grpc server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code in Rx like this :

```
uploadedFiles.ToObservable().Subscribe(uploadedFile =>
            {
                var call = client.TransferFiles(uploadedFile);
                while (call.ResponseStream.MoveNext())
                {
                    var currentFile = call.ResponseStream.Current;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(currentFile.Message);
                }
            });
```